# Reference for bicategories

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, higher-category-theory

I've learned a bit of bicategories from Jean Bénabou's "Introduction to Bicategories". Now I'm looking for some more comprehensive references concerning this subject this subject. I'm in particular interested the limits, colimits, Yoneda Lemma of bicategories, the structure we can define on the functor category or pseudofunctor category of bicategories, and the model structures on bicategories.

Comment: There is Tom Leinsters https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9810017 which has the coherence theorem. That might be more introductory than what you are looking for though (I don't know much about bicategories, having mainly studied $2$-categories).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft thanks, this paper lists a lot of results I'm interested in, but doesn't include proofs for most of them, which is not good for me. However I do find some suitable books in its reference list.

Comment: Yeah, that paper is meant as a very short and minimal account of the coherence theorem.

Comment: (Sooner or later) you are going to meet *double categories* as well, these can also be viewed as extensions of bicategories where the 2-cells can go from an arrow $A\to B$ to a $C\to D$.. See https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/double+category

Comment: @Berci I thought notion of double categories is an extension of 2-categories, but not bicategories, of which the extension calls for weak double categories. I'm right?

Comment: @CensiLI Yes, yes, but nowadays the terminology rather tends to call the weak doubly categories simply *double categories* and emphasize the adjective *strong* instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The recent book [2-Dimensional Categories](https://arxiv.org/abs/2002.06055) by Johnson and Yau is a comprehensive introduction to 2-categories and bicategories. I believe it has all the topics you are interested in, save for a discussion of model structures: however, it gives several references to the literature where you can read more about this topic.

One should also mention Lack's [A 2-categories companion](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0702535), which is a more informal introduction, and which covers many of the same topics.